# Getting GWT error while trying to update userinformation stored in mySql

Tags: mysql, jdbc

im getting this error - "java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (6 > number of parameters, which is 5)".

Im trying to update information about my user - trough GWT and MySql - of course

```
public boolean changePersonInfo(Person person) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        try {

            PreparedStatement updatePerson = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE users SET " + "adgangskode = ?, "
                    + "email = ?, " + "alder = ?, " + "tlfnr = ?, " + "WHERE id = ?");

            updatePerson.setString(1, person.getPassword());
            updatePerson.setString(2, person.getEmail());
            updatePerson.setString(3, person.getAge() + "");
            updatePerson.setString(4, person.getPhonenumber());
            updatePerson.setInt(5, person.getId());


            int rowsAffected = updatePerson.executeUpdate();

            if (rowsAffected == 1) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
```

Also have this function that should talk with my clickhandler - and RpcServiceImpl

```
class SettingsClickhandler implements ClickHandler{

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

            currentPerson.setPassword(userView.getSettingsView().getPassBoxChange().getText());
            currentPerson.setEmail(userView.getSettingsView().getEmailBoxChange().getText());
            currentPerson.setAge(Integer.valueOf(userView.getSettingsView().getAgeChangeBox().getText()));
            currentPerson.setPhonenumber(userView.getSettingsView().getTlfChangeBox().getText());



            // The RPC call which through the server updates the user info in the users table in the database
            Service.changePersonInfo(currentPerson, new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {


                }

                /*
                 * Confirmation if the info was updated
                 */
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Boolean isUpdated) {
                    if (isUpdated) {
                        content.getUserView().getSettingsView();
                        userView.getSettingsView().clearTextBoxFields();
                        Window.alert("Aendring lykkes");

                    }else{
                        userView.getSettingsView();
                        Window.alert("Aendring Mislykkes");

                    }
```